# How do i make raycast rotate and make script activate on contact

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

### So im trying to make throw and grab script.

The raycast is only on the right and i dont know how to make it rotate and activate on collision with specific object.
Well im not really sure how to either improve it or make it work how i want.
I'm trying to make it throw in the direction you're swinging with some momentum but pretty much i have no idea how to achive that.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class grabberscript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public bool grabbed;
    RaycastHit2D hit;
    public float distance = 2f;
    public Transform holdpoint;
    public float throwforce;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
        {

            if (!grabbed)
            {
                Physics2D.queriesStartInColliders = false;

                hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.right * transform.localScale.x, distance);

                if (hit.collider != null && hit.collider.tag == "grabbable")
                {
                    grabbed = true;

                }


                //grab
            }
            else if (!Physics2D.OverlapPoint(holdpoint.position, notgrabbed))
            {
                grabbed = false;

                if (hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() != null)
                {

                    hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x, 1) * throwforce;
                }


                //throw
            }


        }

        if (grabbed)
            hit.collider.gameObject.transform.position = holdpoint.position;


    }

    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.green;

        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + Vector3.right * transform.localScale.x * distance);
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of `Vector2.right` use a vector that goes towards where the player is facing. That could be `camera.transform.rotation` for a first-person for instance. (maybe need to normalize the vector, I don't remember)

Comment: Getting  "Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Quaternion' and 'float' " error

Comment: mmm sorry, does `transform.forward` do the trick instead?

Comment: well it still grabs when character is on the left side of object but it doesnt work if im on the right side of object and throwing only throws to right but well. I wonder if there is like a way to make instead of raycast some kind of circle that acts like raycast?